# In which interval the solution exist and unique on the area $R=\{(x,y);|x|\le3,|y|\le2\}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

for the initial value problem  $y'=\frac x{y-1},y(0)=0$

in which interval the solution exist and unique on the area $R=\{(x,y);|x|\le3,|y|\le2\}$

$-2/3\le x\le2/3$

$-2/3\le x\le3$

$-3\le x\le3$

$-1\le x\le1$

$-2\le x\le2$

I guess the solution is $(y-1)^2-x^2=1$ and  y' and $\frac {dy'}{dx}$ y=1 is not continous. How can I continue:/

Comment: What do you know about Picard-Lindelöf theorem?

Comment: @qmd thank you. I got it